# Percentage Totals for Column Groups Using MySQL

Tags: mysql

If I have a table with the following:

```
+---------+-------------+
| Country | campaign_id |
+---------+-------------+
| US      |           1 |
| FR      |           1 |
| FR      |           1 |
| UK      |           1 |
| NL      |           2 |
| DE      |           2 |
+---------+-------------+
```

How do I return the percentages for each country like this:

```
+---------+------------+
| Country | Percentage |
+---------+------------+
| US      | 25         |
| FR      | 50         |
| UK      | 25         |
+---------+------------+
```

This is where I'm up to so far:

```
SELECT country FROM campaigns WHERE campaign_id = 1
```

Just to note, it's ok to return 0.25 if that is easier.

Comment: On which field do you wants to calculate Percentage?

Comment: Could this not be done using a simple calculation after you pull the records? SELECT * FROM Table WHERE campaign_id = 1. Then count the number of rows ang generate the percent from here. You dont want to further complicate the SQL query when it would be simple to do this with code.

Comment: The percentage of each country....so say 55.6% US, 12.4% PL, etc

Comment: @DanHastings Not when I'm querying a million rows no.

Comment: What are you dividing to get those percentages?

Comment: @Barmar the total number of records that has campaign_id = 1

Comment: You are querying millions, but the result returned will be a lot less. IF you are going to be returning millions of rows in a single query you will have a different issue on your hands.

Comment: @DanHastings I'm looking to return a summary table of country composition where campaign_id = 1. Not mass data :)

Comment: Got there, thanks all :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a subquery to get the total number of rows in the campaign, and then divide that into the number of rows grouped by country.

```
SELECT a.country, ROUND(100 * COUNT(*)/b.total, 2) AS percentage
FROM yourTable AS a
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS total
  FROM yourTable
  WHERE campaign_id = 1) AS b
WHERE a.campaign_id = 1
GROUP BY a.country
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/df4903/3)

Comment: That works perfectly - thanks this was driving me insane!

Answer (score 1):

for what you've given (looks like counting number of countries with a specific id):

```
SELECT country, ((COUNT(campaign_id)*100)/(SELECT SUM(campaign_id) FROM campaigns WHERE campaign_id = 1)) AS percent
FROM campaigns
WHERE campaign_id = 1
GROUP BY country
```

Comment: Thanks, bit too late unlucky :)

Comment: Hmmmm, this has no subquery. Maybe this is more efficient? If it is I'll accept this instead.

Comment: Ah wait, I see subquery nm :)

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution for your case:

```
SELECT Country,
        (campaign_id/((select SUM(campaign_id) FROM table1 where campaign_id = 1))*100) as percentage
FROM tablename
WHERE campaign_id = 1
GROUP BY Country, campaign_id
```

Comment: Thanks, bit too late unlucky :)

Comment: No problem :P i create your table and your case in my localDB :P

Comment: Why are you summing campaign_id instead of just counting rows? IDs aren't usually something you do arithmetic on, they're just identifiers.